# Make material looks less 'shiny'?

Tags: modeling, cycles-render-engine, materials, bezier-curves

I'm making a model on Blender, and i'm adding texture for it on Cycles, i added a Diffuse BSDF material, on a curves i made but with the lighting (it does need to be with that kind of light) the color seems too shiny/bright, how can i make it look not too bright and maybe even with a little shadow?

[image]

Comment: Not too sure what you mean.. But that's a very bright and saturated blue. Perhaps you might try using a darker, less saturated color?

Comment: It worked i think, i also added a little saturation by controling the colors, thanks :)

Comment: You can increase the Roughness value of Diffuse node to 1.000. It may help a bit.

Comment: @Gonzou I think that would actually decrease the amount of shadow.

Comment: This is just my suggestion.  With roughness set to 1, the light is more diffused on a surface, which makes the contrast between light and shadow less visible. Illuminated areas are less shiny and the shady areas are less sharp. If you then darken it and desaturate it a bit (like gandalf3 suggested) the final effect may work better in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mix shader with a dark ambient occlusion node, colored to fit your object, factored mostly toward the diffuse might help depending on what results you're looking for.

Otherwise I would suggest moving the light farther away, that will at least soften out the white highlights